# High-End 2D Java (SE) Graphics Library

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I am looking for a high-end graphics library for Java Standard Edition. I know some fairly low-level libraries: AWT/Swing, JOGL, SDL. Are/is there an alternative?

My requirements are (atleast):

- Anti-aliased
- Fullscreen support
- Alpha channel
- Blend modes and Z-depth
- Rasterized Effects: (motion) blur, glow, gloom, etc.

And, optionally:

- Hardware acceleration
- Vector graphics (scale/rotate/translate in floating point precision)
- Well documentated, easy to get started.

I understand if there are no libraries/frameworks matching *all* requirements, if so, can you comment on how well it's extendible?

**Edit**:

Are there any other alternatives besides Processing? Is Processing usable (and easy?) as a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a graphics library but rather an advanced applet AND graphics library:
[PulpCore](http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/)

Be sure to grab a quite recent version (maybe even fetch the source via mercurial and build it yourself) because the filter effects you mentioned (blur etc.) aren't available in earlier versions.
I know it might not be exactly what you're looking for; it is not a processing alternative, but it might be the better choice, depending on what you're planning to do.

Comment: FYI PulpCore doesn't appear to exist any more...

Comment: @chriswynnyk too bad. From https://code.google.com/p/pulpcore/ : PulpCore is no longer maintained - please use PlayN or libgdx instead.

Answer (score 5):

All of the effects you ask for can be done with Java 2D fairly simply and Java2D is to some degree hardware accelerated.  The book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://www.filthyrichclients.org/) shows how to implement all of these effects and many others.  [Painters](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/20/introducing-painters) in the [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) has also implemented several of these effects.

Another possibility is [JavaFx](http://javafx.com/).  It has a lot of effects built in.  A year and a half ago when  I tried it, it was still a little slow, but at least one version has been released since then.  It may be more performant now.  It's built on top of Java2D, so it should be able to take advantage of the hardware acceleration in Java2D.

As far as full screen support [here's more information](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe **Processing** ([homepage](http://processing.org/)) can be a good tradeoff.

- it has 4 kinds of backing, including **OpenGL**
- it has AA
- it is 2d or 3d
- it supports hw acceleration
- it supports transformations
- its syntax is quite easy to learn
- it's easily embeddable
- everything you need to learn is in [this](http://processing.org/reference/) page

Comment: Can processing be used as a library?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://processing.org